# Seeking multi-dimensional array tutorial material

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, ios, multidimensional-array

I want to know about multidimensional arrays on iPhone. Can anyone please explain it to me or give me some links? I'm new to iPhone programming. Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check the below SO post

[How to create nested array or multidimensional array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1125918/how-to-create-nested-array-or-multidimensional-array)

[Multidimensional Arrays](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5025861/multidimensional-arrays)

[multidimensional array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5563692/multidimensional-array)

[Objective C - Create a multi-dimensional array with the dimensions specified at initialisation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4982617/objective-c-create-a-multi-dimensional-array-with-the-dimensions-specified-at-i)

[Multidimensional array in objective c](http://www.cocos2d-iphone.org/forum/topic/13570)